# FAKE (F# Make) - Is it possible to ignore compiler warnings for a given build target?

Tags: build, msbuild, f#-fake

The title says it all really.

I want to ignore compiler warnings & stop them being logged for a certain build target.

I am building with a statement similar to this and want to be able to pass a parameter or change the statement to suppress compiler warnings:

```
Target "BuildConfigX" (fun _ ->
    !! "**/*.csproj"
    |> MSBuildDebug buildDir "Build"
    |> Log "AppBuild-Output")
```

I had a bit of a google and a bit of a hunt through the docs but couldn't find anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WarningLevel` build property should potentially do the trick. Something like below:

```
let buildProject outputDir buildTargets projectName = 
    let propertiesCommon =            
                [   "DevEnvDir", "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools"
                    "OutputPath", outputDir
                    "Optimize", "True"
                    "DebugSymbols", "True"
                    "Configuration", buildMode ]
    let properties = 
        match buildMode with
            | "Release" -> propertiesCommon @ ["WarningLevel", "0"] //<--
            | _ -> propertiesCommon

    let setParams defaults =
        { defaults with
            Verbosity = Some(Minimal)
            Targets = buildTargets
            Properties = properties
        }
    build setParams projectName |> DoNothing


Target "BuildConfigX" (fun _ ->
    !! "**/*.csproj"
    |> Seq.iter (buildProject buildOutDir ["ReBuild"])
    )
```